# How do I run a report for an event

Tags: civireport, reports

How do I run a report on an event that includes things such as participant name, email and organisation they are from?

Answer (score 2):

The best approach depends on what you intend to do with the list, but generally speaking you'll use the **Reports** menu as follows:

- In the CiviCRM menu, click **Reports menu » Event Reports**.
- Select **Attendee List**.
- Click the **Columns** tab.  Check the box next to **Email** and **Current Employer** (and anything else you need).
- Click the **Filters** tab.  In the **Event** box, select the event(s) you want a report on.
- Click the **View Results** (or **Refresh Results** if you already pressed it once).[image]